# Error in deployment of gulp based website

Tags: node.js, gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-sass, gulp-filter

I am trying to deploy a gulp based website but i get this error every time i do gulp deploy i encounter this problem can anyone help?

```
$ gulp deploy
[00:19:01] Using gulpfile E:\newfolder\gulpfile.js
[00:19:01] Starting 'deploy'...
[00:19:04] 'deploy' errored after 2.48 s
[00:19:04] TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null
    at Function.module.exports.Commit.actor (E:\newfolder\node_modules\gift\lib\commit.js:145:56)
    at Function.module.exports.Commit.parse_commits (E:\newfolder\node_modules\gift\lib\commit.js:113:21)   
    at E:\newfolder\node_modules\gift\lib\commit.js:55:39
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:374:7)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:400:28)
    at ChildProcess.emit (domain.js:537:15)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1058:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:293:5)
    at Process.callbackTrampoline (internal/async_hooks.js:130:17)
```

this is my gulpfile.js

```
/*
* Gulpfile
* @version: 1.0.0 (Fri, 08 May 2020)
* @author: HtmlStream
* @license: Htmlstream (https://htmlstream.com/licenses)
* Copyright 2020 Htmlstream
*/

require('./gulpfiles/watch')
require('./gulpfiles/dist')
require('./gulpfiles/build')
require('./gulpfiles/preview')
require('./gulpfiles/svg-compiler')
require('./gulpfiles/deploy')
require('./gulpfiles/ga')
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had this error. I created the gh-pages branch myself and pushed to this branch the contents of the **dist** folder. Unfortunately, only manually in my case, the only way it worked.